# Can We Prove Cohen's Theorem for Modules by Using Cohen's Theorem for Rings?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian

Let $R$ be a ring. We have:

> **Cohen's theorem for Rings.** If all prime ideals of $R$ are finitely generated, then $R$ is Noetherian.

Now let $M$ be an $R$-module. We have

> **Cohen's Theorem for Modules.** Let $M$ be finitely generated and further assume that $\mathfrak pM$ is finitely generated for each prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in $R$. Then $M$ is Noetherian.

One can adopt the standard proof of Cohen's Theorem for Rings to prove Cohen's Theorem for Modules. But is there a short cut if we assume the former to prove the latter?

Comment: I would try to use Nagata's principle of idealization.